# Using the Page Object Model is it better practice to return a promise or to use async/await in the function when the function does not return a value

Tags: selenium-webdriver, async-await, protractor, pageobjects

Hoping to get some feedback on what is the best practice in this situation 
*(Protractor testing framework using page object model with async/await instead of SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER)*.

Let say I have a function called `setUsername` which simply sets the username in a field. I'm wondering is it better practice to use async/await to await the action in the function itself or to return the action. Either way whenever the function is called it will need to be awaited.

**option1**

```
this.setUsername = async function (username) {
    await usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
}
```

**option2**

```
this.setUsername = function (username) {
    return usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
}
```

**Syntax for calling either option**

```
await loginPO.setUsername('admin');
```

**Reasoning:** If I go with option1 then I am declaring await twice (in func and when called), which seems unnecessary, but the function behaves more inline with what I expect. If I go with option 2 then await is only used once but it seems wrong to return anything from a function where I only need to set a value and not get anything back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is better to use **option 1**, where you will explicit show that your function is `async` because has some actions that need to be awaited.

So, everyone will understand that for using it function will be needed to resolve a promise.
Also, if your method will have two or more actions that are needed to be awaited, so, you will have to make your function `async`.

Comment: Agreed. If multiple actions take place in the function then option 2 will not work and you end up having mixed conventions.

Comment: Ok this makes sense to me also. Thanks for the feedback