# Am I using async await the right way? In TypeScript

Tags: typescript, async-await, protractor

I am not sure if I am using async/await the right way in my TypeScript and Protractor code. If you see the below code, the spec says await and calls the page object which in turn is async/await. The page object calls another method which is again async/await. Is this the proper implementation? Are there any best practices? I feel like I am using async/await everywhere.

**Spec:**

```
await login.loginTomySiteTools();
```

**Page Object:**

```
async loginTomySiteTools(): Promise<void> {
    await this.helper.enterText(this.email, this.mySuperApp.userID);
    await this.helper.click(this.btnNext);
}
```

**helper:**

```
async enterText(element: WebElement, textToEnter: string): Promise<void> {
    await browser.sleep(1000);
    await element.sendKeys(textToEnter);
}
```

Comment: It looks good. I don't know how Protractor works and where you write the `await login.loginTomySiteTools();` call but it needs to stay in an `async function`. More than that, a function that calls an `async` function must know that the callee is `async` and returns a `Promise`. Otherwise the code of the callee will complete after the control is returned to the caller and the expectations on the callee's behaviour will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @axiac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As strange as it may seem, from my understanding, **you are using it in the correct way**. It is just the nature of Protractor that all browser actions are wrapped with Promises (which require awaits) and then with the Page Object Model all the functions we declare in our page objects (which often contain browser actions) will also require awaits. We end up with a lot of awaits for the same action.

I actually asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693279/using-the-page-object-model-is-it-better-practice-to-return-a-promise-or-to-use) not so long ago, I'm unsure if these questions are similar enough to be marked as duplicates so I won't flag it for now.

In terms of best practices I think the approach you are taking is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't find a better answer anywhere else. Yes, you and I are asking the same question but from different perspectives. The end goal is same though but I couldn't find your question from a basic search.You can mark this duplicate if you wish to but I would suggest that you rephrase your question to make it searchable for the general audience. :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you my question was much more specific so I don't think these are duplicates. I wanted to share the answers I got in case you found it helpful but was hoping this question would generate some more technical answers than mine received.

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting the same but it looks like a lot of people KNOW it I guess :) :)